# Pygame rectangles not drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm not exactly new to python, but I am new to pygame. I've written a basic script that should build a grid of thin rectangles of random shades of grey. as far as I can tell it's building the objects properly and all the relevant variables seem to be working. but pygame will not draw the rectangles. I'm sure its something fairly simple, can someone point out my mistake?

*just to clarify, the prints were for testing purposes*

```
#simple pygame grid drawer
import pygame as pg
import random as r

pg.init()
X = 600
Y = 600
surface_screen = pg.display.set_mode((X , Y))
colors = [(i , i , i) for i in range(255)]

class line:
    def __init__(self , x , y , hight , width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = r.choice(colors)
        self.hight = hight
        self.width = width
        
lines = []
lines.append([line(x*50 , Y , Y , 15) for x in range(X // 50)])
lines.append([line(X , y*50 , 15 , X) for y in range(Y // 50)])
print("yep1")    
for A in lines:
    for i in A:
        pg.draw.rect(surface_screen , i.color , pg.Rect(i.x , i.y , i.hight , i.width))
        print(f"yep2 {i.color} , X:{i.x} , Y:{i.y} , hight:{i.hight} , width:{i.width}")

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
    
        pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()
```

Comment: I haven't used pygame before, but I'd take a close look at the coordinates of the rectangles you're generating -- if pygame works the way one would expect, every rectangle should be outside of the bounds of the screen.

Comment: I agree, the rectangles are out of bounds, because either the x or the  y coordinate of the rectangle is 600. e.g. change to `lines.append([line(x*50, 0, 15, Y) for x in range(X // 50)])` and 
`lines.append([line(0, y*50, Y, 15) for y in range(Y // 50)])`

Comment: Oh i see, i didnt take into consideration that 0,0 was in the middle of the screen, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangles are out of bounds, because either the `x` or the `y` coordinate of the rectangle is 600.
Change the following lines of code:

<s>`lines.append([line(x*50 , Y , Y , 15) for x in range(X // 50)])`</s>

```py
lines.append([line(x*50, 0, 15, Y) for x in range(X // 50)])
```

<s>`lines.append([line(X , y*50 , 15 , X) for y in range(Y // 50)])`</s>

```py
lines.append([line(0, y*50, Y, 15) for y in range(Y // 50)])
```